# Ruby loop break inconsistencies?

Tags: ruby, loops, conditional-statements, break

This works:

```
#Loop naming accounts====================

num = 0 #<--Generic counting variable

loop do

    print ("\nEnter account name or press 'q': > ")

    names[num] = gets.chomp

        if names[num] == "q"
            break   
        end

    puts ("The account name is #{names[num]}.")

    num += 1

end
```

The obvious problem here is that I don't want "q" to be one of the accounts.

This doesn't work:

```
#Loop naming accounts====================

num = 0 #<--Generic counting variable

loop do

    print ("\nWould you like to add an account? [1 - yes] [2 - no]: > ")

    varr = nil

    varr = gets.chomp.to_i

    if varr == 2
        break
    end

    names[num] = gets.chomp

    puts ("The account name is #{names[num]}.")

    num += 1

end
```

This sends my terminal to a completely black screen.  Questions:

1. Why does the first example work for breaking out of the loop, but the second one will not?
2. Why is the second example weirdly breaking to a completely blank screen rather than throwing an error, etc?
3. How do I properly do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The second example works fine if you quit with 2.
2. The problem is that you ask the user to enter first if they want to add an account or not, and then you expect a second input which is the name of the account, but you don't print anything to the user, try with this code:

---

```
num = 0 #<--Generic counting variable
names = [] # Collection for names

loop do
  print ("\nWould you like to add an account? [1 - yes] [2 - no]: > ")
  varr = gets.chomp.to_i
  break if varr == 2

  puts "Enter name"
  names[num] = gets.chomp
  puts ("The account name is #{names[num]}.")

  num += 1
end
```

Comment: I must have something wrong on my end because my terminal is still going completely blank when breaking out of the loop.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out.  Once I fixed the loop with your help, another loop was using the names array to count up to account "q", which didn't exist once we changed the break in this loop.  Thanks for your help.